# OnClickEvent in Excel with iterating rows

Tags: excel, vba, onclick

I have  kind of the questionnaire. There is some identification number in the first column. The other three columns contain possible answers. I need to make sure that when I clicked on one of the cells under the columns with the answer options, an identification number appears in this row. I understand how this can be done for a specific case, but cannot extend this to all rows.

E.G. I have 2-10 numbers in A2-A10 rows.
I also have B1-D1 column headers with answers.
I clicked on B2 and "2" was put in B2 cell.
In the next row I clicked D3 and "3" was put in D3 cell etc.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)       
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
 With ActiveWindow
 actRow = ActiveCell.Row
 If ActiveCell.Value = Cells(actRow, 1) Then
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
 Else
    ActiveCell.Value = Cells(actRow, 1)
 End If
 End With
 End If
End Sub
```